# Selenium - Render page from string html

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Selenium webdriver for automation tests using Java. The problem is that instead of having an url, I have a string which contains the html. Is there a way to render that html in order to use the webdriver?
Or is there another option for testing with that html string?

Comment: What if you would write the source to a html file (temporary file) and you open that file in the browser? (driver.get("file:///home/user/temp/mypage.html")), and once you are done with the test, you can delete the file.
Or you could also inject the code with javascript with webdriver. (Although I have not tried this one yet)

Comment: The temporary file idea is a great idea.  However, if you would tell us more of what you are trying to do, I bet that there's a more efficient way than using WebDriver.

Comment: I'll try with the temporary file.

Comment: Injecting with JavaScript works well